# Changing color of a chechboxTableViewer input JFace

Tags: jface, tableviewer

I am having a CheckboxTableViewer with several entries. Now I need to display a few of the entries in a different color. Kindly help me to do this as I am very new to this topic. Thanks in advance.

```java
checkboxTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(composite,
            SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
checkboxTableViewer.setColumnProperties(new String[] {});
checkboxTableViewer.setAllChecked(false);
checkboxTableViewer.setAllGrayed(false);
table = checkboxTableViewer.getTable();
table.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 8, SWT.NORMAL));
table.setBounds(0, 10, 805, 277);
checkboxTableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(
            new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
checkboxTableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
checkboxTableViewer.setInput(listSelCommit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Label Provider implement `IColorProvider`, this adds two methods to the provider:

```java
public MyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements IColorProvider
{
  ... other label provider methods

  @Override
  public Color getForeground(Object element)
  {
    // TODO return foreground color for 'element' or null to use the default
  }

  @Override
  public Color getBackground(Object element)
  {
    // TODO return background color for 'element' or null to use the default
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what exactly I should do. I am new to this topic. Thankyou

Comment: As I don't know what objects your content provider is providing or how you want to select the colors it is difficult to provide any more detail.